# What do I need to do to access `currentPage` and `setCurrentPage` inside my render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-a-custom-pagination-component-in-react/) web article to implement pagination.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Config from 'config';
import { formatter } from '../common.js'
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import Pagination from '../Pagination';
import "./Order.css";

let PageSize = 25;

class Portal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            apiData: [],
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {        
        console.log('app mounted');

        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        const token = JSON.parse(tokenString);

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token
        });
        
        const response = await fetch(Config.apiUrl + `/api/Orders/GetAllInvoices`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({ orderList: json });
    }

    render() {
        const orders = this.state.orderList;
        const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);  <<== Error here

        const currentTableData = useMemo(() => {
            const firstPageIndex = (currentPage - 1) * PageSize;
            const lastPageIndex = firstPageIndex + PageSize;
            return orders.slice(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex);
        }, [currentPage]);

        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Portal</h2>
                <br />
                <h3>Past Orders</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="number">Invoice Number</th>
                            <th className="date">Invoice Date</th>
                            <th className="amount">Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {currentTableData && currentTableData.map(order =>
                            <tr key={order.sopnumbe}>
                                <td>{order.sopnumbe}</td>
                                <td>{format(Date.parse(order.docdate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}</td>
                                <td>{formatter.format(order.docamnt)}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Pagination
                    className="pagination-bar"
                    currentPage={currentPage}
                    totalCount={orders.length}
                    pageSize={PageSize}
                    onPageChange={page => setCurrentPage(page)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Portal;
```

As it is a class component I am getting an error 'Invalid hook call' trying to `useHook` inside a class component as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

I have tried moving this into an outside function and call `foo()` inside my render:

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from "react";
import Config from 'config';
import { formatter } from '../common.js'
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import Pagination from '../Pagination';
import "./Order.css";

let PageSize = 25;

function foo() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
}
...
```

But now what do I need to do to access `currentPage` and `setCurrentPage` inside my render function, add `this.` or move the `const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)` line into the `componentDidMount`?

Comment: Class components don't support hooks. If you want to use hooks (`useState`, `useEffect`..), you can start by writing new code as functional components with hooks. You can read more about Hooks-FAQ [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are meant to be written in functional components and not class components.

To write the same logic. with class components, you need to declare the state like you have already done in the constructor and use lifecycle methods

```js
class Portal extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: 'React',
            apiData: [],
            orderList: [],
            currentPage: 1,
            currentTableData: [],
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {        
        console.log('app mounted');

        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        const token = JSON.parse(tokenString);

        let headers = new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.token
        });
        
        const response = await fetch(Config.apiUrl + `/api/Orders/GetAllInvoices`, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers
        });
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({ orderList: json });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
        if(prevState.currentPage !== this.state.currentPage) {
            const firstPageIndex = (currentPage - 1) * PageSize;
            const lastPageIndex = firstPageIndex + PageSize;
            this.setState({currentTableData: orders.slice(firstPageIndex, lastPageIndex)});
       }
    }
    render() {
        const orders = this.state.orderList;
        const currentTableData = this.state.currentTableData;
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Portal</h2>
                <br />
                <h3>Past Orders</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="number">Invoice Number</th>
                            <th className="date">Invoice Date</th>
                            <th className="amount">Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {currentTableData && currentTableData.map(order =>
                            <tr key={order.sopnumbe}>
                                <td>{order.sopnumbe}</td>
                                <td>{format(Date.parse(order.docdate), 'MM/dd/yyyy')}</td>
                                <td>{formatter.format(order.docamnt)}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Pagination
                    className="pagination-bar"
                    currentPage={currentPage}
                    totalCount={orders.length}
                    pageSize={PageSize}
                    onPageChange={page => this.setState({currentPage: page})}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Portal;
```

Comment: I made you changes, but I am getting an error `orders is undefined` on line `totalCount={orders.length}`.

Comment: initialize orderList state to be empty array in the constructor

Comment: Now I get a error `TypeError: paginationRange is undefined` In `Pagination.js` line 28. By the way, thanks for the great web article.

Comment: @Randy, are you following the freeCodeCamp article?

Comment: Yes, I am. `Pagination.js` is exactly the same.

Comment: We will have to handle a case where totalCount is zero, I think that is missing in the article

Comment: I changed line 28 to `if (currentPage === 0 || typeof paginationRange === 'undefined' || paginationRange.length < 2)`. I get no error now but I also get no items.

Comment: Does state have proper value for orderList?

Comment: Yes, I changed the `Portal` line `if (prevState.currentPage !== this.state.currentPage)` to `if (prevState.currentPage !== this.state.currentPage || prevState.orderList !== this.state.orderList)`. It shows twenty-five Items now but the `Pagination` line doesn't show.

Comment: I had a typo in `currentPage={currentPage}`. I fixed it and everything is working. Thank you.